# Flipping nodes in a pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I only want to flip the nodes for "Pecan" and "Peach" in the pie chart.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (120:3);
\draw (O) -- (210:3);
\draw (O) -- (230:3);
\draw (O) -- (270:3);
\draw (O) -- (310:3);

\path (O) -- node{Vanilla} (60:3);
\path (O) -- node{Chocolate} (165:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=220]{Pecan} (220:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=250]{Peach} (250:3);
\path (O) -- node{Mint} (290:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=335]{Strawberry} (335:3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Do you mean like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hscr5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You mean to rotate the labels to the other direction? Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (120:3);
\draw (O) -- (210:3);
\draw (O) -- (230:3);
\draw (O) -- (270:3);
\draw (O) -- (310:3);

\path (O) -- node{Vanilla} (60:3);
\path (O) -- node{Chocolate} (165:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=45]{Pecan} (220:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=70]{Peach} (250:3);
\path (O) -- node{Mint} (290:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=335]{Strawberry} (335:3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.  Why does `rotate=45` get me `Pecan` displayed the way I want but `rotate=220` does not?

Comment: Because it rotates counterclockwise. Consider [this image](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/PNG/polar-coordinates-template.png): if you say `45` it will go in a diagonal position, but if you say `220`, it will end up upside down.

Comment: @Alenanno  Why `45`?  Why not `67` or `73` or `90` for displaying `Pecan`?

Comment: If a regular word is written at 0 degrees (going ->) and the beginning of the word is the hinge, then if you rotate it by 45 degrees it will be written diagonally. If you increase the degrees it will "rotate" counterclockwise.

Comment: @Alenanno  In the code provided by `adn`, what is the hinge for `Peach`?  I do not know how `rotate=45` gets `Pecan` displayed properly in the pie chart.

Comment: I try the best angle by hand. Just trial and error to see which angle was the best. Probably you can try to align the code in the middle of the pie automatically, but you should ask that as another question.

Comment: Instead of manual rotating by either `220` or `220-180` degree, you can just add the option `sloped` (there's also `allow upside down` which defaults to `false`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  Are you saying that I should compile the code by replacing `rotate=220` with `sloped`, and if that doesn't work, I replace `sloped` with `allow upside down`, and that will work?

Comment: @Alenanno  Recall that with my code, "Pecan" and "Peach" were typeset upside-down. "Pecan" is placed in a node on a line inclined at an angle of 220 degrees.  One user used `rotate=45` to get it displayed properly.  I think "45" can be replaced with many numbers to get the proper display. Another member suggested to just use `sloped` or `sloped, allow upside down` and one of these will give me the display that I want.  Is that correct?

Comment: @user74973 If Qrr suggested that, then it will work. :D If you have doubts about the rotation, you can ask a question on that. But no, not all degrees are the same.

Comment: @Alenanno  Yep.  I'll post a question about that.

Comment: @user74973 Ping me here when you do.

Comment: @Alenanno  See my post at `Flipping nodes in a pie chart - more specific`.